# Deployment fails for app engine flexible enviornment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-flexible

Using sample:https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-app-engine

running:

```
VSKUMAR-mac:getting-started vskumar$ mvn appengine:deploy
gives:
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.246 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-27T00:19:55-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/313M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project endpoints: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy failed: Found 'Dockerfile' in the App Engine directory. Please move it to the Docker directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I tried that but then error changed to:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.395 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-27T00:22:19-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/313M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project endpoints: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy failed: Found an unexpected 'Docker' file in the App Engine directory. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this GitHub pull request, which should fix this problem:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/pull/585